# Having trouble with IUrlHelper

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0

I have a method like so:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Index(string token)
```

And when i use the following line:

```
string url = Url.Action("Index", "Confirm", "mViH%2BZBz4l2%2Bx97rackKlFTWLVeD4xl9c%2B6ggbjbXzpAT%2BLP%2BKWvLqGymZSgV7GEPoXPSRHx6vO1ytaKPbfYrON%2BqP21EGMop3hW1%2BwoHL0Xf7bDSS5EHiqyuwNmiiJiMAYZPgr%2FCe%2FXyZFLCy%2FbfuGCOK3iawGOhdD0DyignbUC3xNybkfZkJNaXNHJlHnIv5eu8Z4wjzFkMmb1SOi5YmIzfT%2FjFovhy6fVFbDQXsc0GBzKqNsZjCudTKSPbMoRV6%2FAjw%3D%3D");
```

url ends up being:

```
"/Confirm?Length=292"
```

Instead of:

```
"/Confirm?token=mViH%2BZBz4l2%2Bx97rackKlFTWLVeD4xl9c%2B6ggbjbXzpAT%2BLP%2BKWvLqGymZSgV7GEPoXPSRHx6vO1ytaKPbfYrON%2BqP21EGMop3hW1%2BwoHL0Xf7bDSS5EHiqyuwNmiiJiMAYZPgr%2FCe%2FXyZFLCy%2FbfuGCOK3iawGOhdD0DyignbUC3xNybkfZkJNaXNHJlHnIv5eu8Z4wjzFkMmb1SOi5YmIzfT%2FjFovhy6fVFbDQXsc0GBzKqNsZjCudTKSPbMoRV6%2FAjw%3D%3D"
```

Does anyone know why this is the case? Nothing i've tried has worked to go around this. And if i create the link manually and use it it will work.

Comment: Because you need to provide an expression `Url.Action("Index", "Confirm", new { token = "...." })`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to provide route values.

> An object that contains the parameters for a route. The parameters
>   are retrieved  through reflection by examining the properties of the
>   object. The object  is typically created by using object initializer
>   syntax.

```
string url = Url.Action("Index", "Confirm", new { token = "...." });
```